# Downloading a file after storing it in SQL Server 2008 Data Base

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, file-upload, file

WEB FRAMEWORK: ASP.NET in C#

Hey guys, I've looked all over the web for something that would show me how to do this but can't find it. I have a page that uploads information about an individual including a resume in the form of a doc docx or pdf. I can upload the file okay but I do not know how to, on another page, To download the file that was loaded to that person's row in the database. Here is the upload code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);
    string contenttype = String.Empty;

    switch (ext)
    {
        case ".doc":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            break;
        case ".docx":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            break;
        case ".pdf":
            contenttype = "application/pdf";
            break;
   }
    if (contenttype.Equals(String.Empty))
    {
        Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('You have selected an invalid resume type.')</script>");
        return;
    }
    Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=;" + "password=;server=;" +
                                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                  "database=contractors; " +
                                  "connection timeout=30");
     try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception el)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(el.ToString());
    }


    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Command String", myConnection);
    myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO contractor (firstName, lastName,phone,email,company,location,fileName,contentType,data,date) " +
                    "Values (@sqlfirstName,@sqllastName,@sqlphone,@sqlemail,@sqlcompany,@sqllocation,@Name,@ContentType,@Data,@sqldate)";


    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contenttype;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Data", System.Data.SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@sqlfirstName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@sqllastName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@sqlemail", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 75).Value = TextBox4.Text;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@sqlphone", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = TextBox3.Text;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@sqlcompany", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = TextBox5.Text;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@sqllocation", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 70).Value = TextBox6.Text;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@sqldate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, 30).Value = DateTime.Now;


    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    try
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('You information has been submitted. Thank you.')</script>");

   }

 }
```

After the information in uploaded I have another page that displays the information to an admin user using a gridview. Would someone help me out with how to translate this back into a downloadable file? Here is The ASP.net code

```
<div>
    <div class="article">

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" emptydatatext="No data available"
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Get Resume" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="firstName" HeaderText="First Name" 
                    SortExpression="firstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lastName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                    SortExpression="lastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="Phone Number" 
                    SortExpression="phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="company" HeaderText="Company" 
                    SortExpression="company" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText="Location" 
                    SortExpression="location" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="fileName" HeaderText="fileName" 
                    SortExpression="fileName" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="contentType" HeaderText="contentType" 
                    SortExpression="contentType" Visible="False" />
                </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:contractorsConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [firstName], [lastName], [phone], [email], [company], [location], [fileName], [id], [date], [data], [contentType] FROM [contractor]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Menas onclicking the filename you want to download file right

Comment: 'Console' is not working on asp.net

Answer (score 2):

The way you try to implement the download have several issues and potential problems.

Use an generic handler to read the file, and send the file.

On the gridView add a link to the generic handler and send on query the id of the file that you like to download.

eg  `<a taget="_blank" href="/downloadFile.ashx?id=3">download</a>`

then on ashx you read the 3, and open the database, and then send the file.

### Also

```
 Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('You have selected an invalid resume type.')</script>");
```

This line is bad practice, find some other way to send error to your users and do not use the Respose.Write to render script on the page. Also this script probably is goind to break the DOM on your page and is going to be render on the end of the page, after the body.

The console is not working on asp.net - please take some more time to understand whats and what going on the render of the page.